# how to avoid default form action on laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i integrate my html form on laravel. it has html registration form. in that form i didn't put form action . so when i submit the form it post the data to the same page.but i write a javascipt click event to get form data and post data to the destination with ajax. but when i click the submit button i perform these two actions  .. 1. posting data to the same page and another my ajax call.. i want only ajax. not that .. how to solve this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="addUser">input fields</form>
$('#addUser').on('click',function(){some code})
```

Comment: try `$('#addUser').on('click',function(){ return false; })`

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` is what you're looking for. [Here is the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('#addUser').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 ...rest of the code...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `submit` event of form like this.

```
$(document).on('submit','form#addUser',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //This prevents the default submit action that might refresh the page
    .. code
});
```